# Удаление пары ключ-значение в словаре с использованием .lower()

Tags: python, python-3.7

Нужно удалить из словаря пару ключ-значение независимо от того, каким регистром вводится ключ.

Словарь содержит:

```
'Bob' : '123123',  
'Henry' : '9239829',  
'Sandy' : '98238989'
```

Если вводить ключ регистром, отличным от указанного в ключе, выдает ошибку KeyError, то есть, например, если ввести bob вместо Bob, случится ошибка.

Как сделать так, чтобы ключ удалялся независимо от используемого регистра, чтобы при вводе 'bob' удалялся ключ 'Bob'?

Пробовал сделать так:

```py
delete = input()
        del ab[delete.lower()]
```

и так:

```py
delete = input().lower()
        del ab[delete]
```

Что, по-моему, одно и то же, не работает.

---

UPD получилось удалить ключ с помощью

```py
        delete = input()
        for name in list(ab):
            if name.lower() == delete:
                del ab[name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, итеративно и не очень быстро:

```
ab = your_dict

key_to_delete = 'bob'

for key in list(ab.keys()):
    if key.lower() == key_to_delete:
        del ab[key]
```

Удалять во время перебора - плохая практика.

Comment: Предложенный код выдал ошибку "dictionary changed size during iteration", после гугления нашел решение: вместо ab.keys() использовать list(ab), теперь работает, ключи удаляет, спасибо! А насчёт плохой практики, я пока учусь, производительность не особо волнует, думаю, с опытом придёт всё необходимое :)

Comment: Я имел в виду что не нужно изменять размерность (удалять элементы) итерируемого объекта. Как минимум, во время итерации нужно найти необходимые элементы, а удалить их после окончания итерации.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {'Bob' : '123123',  
'Henry' : '9239829',  
'Sandy' : '98238989' }
key = input()
dic.pop(key if key[0].isupper() else key[0].capitalize() + key[1:])
```

Как-то так.